# How to do file versioning when uploading files to Alfresco using CMIS PHP

Tags: php, alfresco, atom-feed, cmis

I'm using the [Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP client](https://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html) to upload documents from a local folder to Alfresco Community Edition 5.1 via ATOM. Here's the script I'm using to do so:

```
require_once ('cmis_repository_wrapper.php');
require_once ('cmis_service.php');

$repo_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";
$repo_username = "user";
$repo_password = "pass";

$client = new CMISService($repo_url, $repo_username, $repo_password);

$repo_folder = "/alfrescoFolder";
$source_folder = "localFolder/";
$source_files = array_diff(scandir("$source_folder", 1), array('..', '.'));
$myfolder = $client->getObjectByPath($repo_folder);

foreach($source_files as $file)
{
    try
    {
        $upload = $client->createDocumentFromSource($myfolder->id, $file, "$source_folder/$file");
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Some error here.";
    }
}
```

This script works fine and documents are uploaded without problem, provided that the document doesn't already exist in the Alfresco repository. For example, let's say I have a document in my Alfresco repository named `example.txt`, and so, if I try to upload a document from my local folder with the same name, I get a CMIS constraint exception. I dont't know how I can upload a new version of an existing document.

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
$objs = $client->getChildren($myfolder->id);

foreach($source_files as $file)
{
    foreach($objs->objectList as $obj)
    {
        if($obj->properties['cmis:name'] == $file)
        {
            try
            {
                $checkedout = $client->checkOut($obj->id);
                $client->checkIn($checkedout->id);
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo "Some error here.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                $upload = $client->createDocumentFromSource($myfolder->id, $file, "$source_folder/$file", array('cmis:objectTypeId'=>'D:ex:document'));
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo "Some error here";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
DEBUG: postEntry: myURL = http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/checkedoutDEBUG: postEntry: entry_template = {title} {SUMMARY} {CONTENT} {PROPERTIES} DEBUG: postEntry: properties_xml = b549c715-9a9d-427c-bd4b-c6ea29d222cb;1.0 DEBUG: postEntry: hash_values = Array ( [PROPERTIES] => b549c715-9a9d-427c-bd4b-c6ea29d222cb;1.0 [SUMMARY] => {summary} ) DEBUG: postEntry: post_value = b549c715-9a9d-427c-bd4b-c6ea29d222cb;1.0
```

What's funny is that the document is in fact locked for editing, so I don't really know what's going on. I also don't know if checking out and then checking in a document is how I'm supposed to version a document.

**TL;DR**

I want to be able to specify that the document I'm uploading is a new version of an existing document. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [function coverage page](http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpfunctioncoverage.html) on the Apache Chemistry web site lists what the CMIS PHP client can and cannot do. Check out, check in, and cancel checkout are all unsupported at the present time. I know they would welcome contributions.

The underlying CMIS specification supports it, of course, so you can either update the library to support checkout/checkin or use the raw binding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on CMIS, but I think that [this forum post](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/updating-document-cmis-04282011-1513) answers the question. See the answer from "jevon" that provides an example and a link to [this page](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html) (see the "Updating a document" section)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. The links you mention revolve around the Java API. Unfortunately, my knowledge of Java is non-existent. In addition, the CMIS Java API is, as far as I understand, much more feature rich than its PHP counterpart, so I don't know how applicable Java examples would be to PHP.

Comment: Ah, apologies - I should have paid more attention to your question.

Comment: I had a conversation with a colleague who knows more about CMIS and he has confirmed that the versioning servicing are not implemented in the PHP client. At a spec. level you need to be performing checkout and checkin actions - but this is not supported in the PHP client at the time of writing.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear. I'll have to find some other way of implementing this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found out about an alternative [CMIS PHP library](https://github.com/dkd/php-cmis-client) that implements versioning services, including example usage. I've used it to successfully solve the problem I posted in my question.

**Edit: additional information added.**

So, to get versioning working, I used the example code provided in the library. The script I used can be used to create new documents and to update and version existing documents. So, here it is:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
if (!is_file(__DIR__ . '/conf/Configuration.php')) {
    die("Please add your connection credentials to the file \"" . __DIR__ . "/conf/Configuration.php\".\n");
} else {
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/conf/Configuration.php');
}

$major = (boolean) isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : false;

$httpInvoker = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
    array(
        'defaults' => array(
            'auth' => array(
                CMIS_BROWSER_USER,
                CMIS_BROWSER_PASSWORD
            )
        )
    )
);

$parameters = array(
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionParameter::BINDING_TYPE => \Dkd\PhpCmis\Enum\BindingType::BROWSER,
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionParameter::BROWSER_URL => CMIS_BROWSER_URL,
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionParameter::BROWSER_SUCCINCT => false,
    \Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionParameter::HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT => $httpInvoker,
);

$sessionFactory = new \Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionFactory();

// If no repository id is defined use the first repository
if (CMIS_REPOSITORY_ID === null) {
    $repositories = $sessionFactory->getRepositories($parameters);
    $repositoryId = $repositories[0]->getId();
} else {
    $repositoryId = CMIS_REPOSITORY_ID;
}

$parameters[\Dkd\PhpCmis\SessionParameter::REPOSITORY_ID] = $repositoryId;

$session = $sessionFactory->createSession($parameters);
$rootFolder = $session->getObject($session->createObjectId($session->getRootFolder()->getId()));

try {

    $document = null;
    $stream = \GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::factory(fopen($filePath, 'r'));
    foreach ($rootFolder->getChildren() as $child) {
        if ($child->getName() === $fileName) {
            $document = $child;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$document) {

        $properties = array(
            \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::OBJECT_TYPE_ID => 'cmis:document',
            \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::NAME => $fileName
        );

        $document = $session->createDocument($properties, $rootFolder, $stream);
        $document = $session->getObject($document);
    }

    $checkedOutDocumentId = $document->getVersionSeriesCheckedOutId();
    if ($checkedOutDocumentId) {
        $checkedOutDocumentId = $session->createObjectId($checkedOutDocumentId);
    } else {
        $checkedOutDocumentId = $document->checkOut();
    }

    $checkedInDocumentId = $session->getObject($checkedOutDocumentId)->checkIn(
        $major,
        array(
            \Dkd\PhpCmis\PropertyIds::DESCRIPTION => 'New description'
        ),
        $stream,
        'Comments'
    );


} catch (\Dkd\PhpCmis\Exception\CmisVersioningException $e) {
    echo "********* ERROR **********\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo "**************************\n";
    exit();
}
```